# replace the silhouette with the Inertia

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a problem. I am working with `k-means` and would like to find the optimal cluster. Unfortunately, my data set is too large to apply `silhouette` . Is there an option to adapt this code and replace the `silhouette` with the `Inertia`?

MVC

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
              [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
              [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],
              [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],])

kmeans_per_k = [KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=42).fit(X)
                for k in range(1, 10)]
inertias = [model.inertia_ for model in kmeans_per_k]

silhouette_scores = [silhouette_score(X, model.labels_)
                     for model in kmeans_per_k[1:]]


from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FixedFormatter

plt.figure(figsize=(11, 9))

for k in (3, 4, 5, 6):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, k - 2)
    
    y_pred = kmeans_per_k[k - 1].labels_
    silhouette_coefficients = silhouette_samples(X, y_pred)

    padding = len(X) // 30
    pos = padding
    ticks = []
    for i in range(k):
        coeffs = silhouette_coefficients[y_pred == i]
        coeffs.sort()

        color = mpl.cm.Spectral(i / k)
        plt.fill_betweenx(np.arange(pos, pos + len(coeffs)), 0, coeffs,
                          facecolor=color, edgecolor=color, alpha=0.7)
        ticks.append(pos + len(coeffs) // 2)
        pos += len(coeffs) + padding

    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(ticks))
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter(range(k)))
    if k in (3, 5):
        plt.ylabel("Cluster")
    
    if k in (5, 6):
        plt.gca().set_xticks([-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
        plt.xlabel("Silhouette Coefficient")
    else:
        plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

    plt.axvline(x=silhouette_scores[k - 2], color="red", linestyle="--")
    plt.title("$k={}$".format(k), fontsize=16)

#save_fig("silhouette_analysis_plot")
plt.show()
```

What I want with `Inertia`
[image]

Comment: have you tried using mini batch to help with large datasets https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html

Comment: @MuhammadPathan The problem is not that `kMeans` in general takes a long time but that the metric `silhouette` takes a long time to calculate.

Comment: Is a different metric an option? Maybe [Gap statistics](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-and-the-gap-statistics-4c5d414acd29) are an option in your case.

Comment: Another metric would be possible, I would like to graphically illustrate with the help of the code the value of the different metric `Inertia` or another one.

Comment: Well, you can visualize both the intra-cluster distance as well as the gap statistics

Answer (score 2):

First of all I suggest calculating silhouette score on a subset of data using argument `sample_size` and  `random_state` (for reproducibility). This may save you some time, meanwhile calculate and plot rather comprehensive information. ([how to use](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html)). But as you know there are plenty of options for measuring clustering quality along with visualization. The one you've mentioned is **elbow (inertia)** which can be used like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=3, n_features=2,
                  random_state=0)
scores = [KMeans(n_clusters=i+2).fit(X).inertia_ 
          for i in range(10)]
sns.lineplot(np.arange(2, 12), scores)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel("Inertia")
plt.title("Inertia of k-Means versus number of clusters")
```

[image]

This [Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/cluster-analysis-create-visualize-and-interpret-customer-segments-474e55d00ebb) introduces several useful yet easy technique to acquire clustering quality.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to plot the `Inertia` metric instead of the `shihoulette` and this is my question. How can I modify the diagram / chart to show the `Inertia` metric.